# LinqToDB 'Configuration string is not provided.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq2db

I have to use for the first time the LinqToDB library, so I'm reading their step by step:

https://linq2db.github.io/articles/get-started/full-dotnet/existing-db.html

Which basically is:

```
     1-Create a new Project (Done, console one ) 
     2-Install the LinqToDB packages (Done, linq2db.SqlServer installed) 
     3-Generate model from database ( Done, with .tt file) 
     4-Use my model...
```

Here starts the problem, firstly you have to add a .config file, my entire file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-HMRUEF4\SQLSERVER;Database=CrudWF;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I just changed the connectionString to my local database string

Then it's already supposed to work in the main method ...

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var database = new DataModels.CrudWFDB())
        {
            var q = from student in database.Alunos  
                    select student;

            foreach (var student in q)
                Console.WriteLine(student.Nome);
        }
    }
```

**The Problem:**
When I run the app, in the line where `new DataModels.CrudWFDB()` is called it throws an exception:

> LinqToDB.LinqToDBException: 'Configuration string is not provided.'

I didn't edit the autogenerated model class because I think the problem isn't there, but here is the constructor for `CrudWFDB()`:

```
    public CrudWFDB()
    {
        InitDataContext();
        InitMappingSchema();
    }
```

I'm stuck on this part, what can I do?

Comment: Is that your *entire* config file? If so, you're missing the closing tag `</configuration>` and the `<?xml...>` tag. If your XML is malformed it won't load anything.

Comment: Fact, that was the first mistake I made, but even with the correct xml file it didn't work. Soon I'll show how I solved this problem, thank you for your answer anyways ^^